# Knockout - How to access parent properties from nested function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, nested-attributes

Please, can anybody help me with this?

I'm getting the following error when executing the **create** method:

```
*Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'baseUri'*
```

This method is called from the following binding:

```
<form id="createProducts" data-bind="submit: products.create">
```

When the **read** method is executed, called from the **PreLoad** method, both *baseUri* and *items* are available.

I've found solutions to this problem when the view model is defined as a function, but in my case, it's being defined as an object.

This is my full JS file

---

```
var mm = {

    /* Products ********************************************************** */

    products: {

        items: ko.observableArray([]),

        read: function () {
            $.getJSON(this.baseUri(), this.items);
        },

        create: function (formElement) {

            $.post(this.baseUri(), $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
                .done(function (o) {                    
                    alert("The Product " + o.Name + " was created.");
                    this.items.push(o);
                });
        },

        baseUri: function () { return BASE_URI; }
    }

};

function PreLoad() {

    mm.products.read();

    ko.applyBindings(mm);
}
```

---

- **BASE_URI** is a global variable defined in my master page, I need it because I have multiple nested view models (I cut them from this code) and each baseUri is a composition of BASE_URI + "some_string_value". Anyway, i need to access **items** too, in order to update the values that are being displayed in a list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to ensure that `this` is correct when binding an event.

The first is to use `bind`:

```
<form id="createProducts" data-bind="submit: products.create.bind(products)">
```

The second is to use an inline function:

```
<form id="createProducts" data-bind="submit: function() { products.create(); }">
```

Possibly this behavior will change in the future (see https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/378).

EDIT

There are two solutions to make the `this` available in callback functions. The first is to copy `this` to a local variable that will be available through closure.

```
        var self = this;
        $.post(this.baseUri(), $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
            .done(function (o) {                    
                alert("The Product " + o.Name + " was created.");
                self.items.push(o);
            });
```

The second is to use `bind` on the callback function.

```
        $.post(this.baseUri(), $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
            .done(function (o) {                    
                alert("The Product " + o.Name + " was created.");
                this.items.push(o);
            }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! The first option partly solved the issue. The **this.baseUri** is now available, but the **this.items** is undefined. Maybe because it is inside the **.done(function**.

Comment: Correct. I've expanded the answer to deal with that also.

Comment: Perfect Michael! I try that but I was placing the binding in the wrong place ( `}).bind` instead of `}.bind` ). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling `this` isn't what you think it is when you call `products.create`. Try using `.bind` to set the context explicitly:

```
<form id="createProducts" data-bind="submit: products.create.bind($data)">
```

Comment: Hi Andrew! I tested your suggestion but the remains the same.
I read an article about this context issue. According the item 5 (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html), ~this~ wil represent the context of the caller. The form in this case, this is why my function can't find items or baseUri properties.

Comment: The article suggest to apply ".bind(viewModel)" (mm in my code) to the function, but the error persists.

Comment: What if you use `.bind($root)`?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew Whitaker already mentioned - "this" will be not the context you are expecting. My solution would be to store "this" reference (eg called "self") and use it instead of "this":

```
products: {
    self: undefined,
    items: ...,
    init: function() { 
        this.self = this; 
    },
    read: function () {$.getJSON(self.baseUri(), self.items);},
    create: function () {
        $.post(self.baseUri(), $(formElement).serialize(), null, "json")
            .done(function (o) {                    
                alert("The Product " + o.Name + " was created.");
                self.items.push(o);
            });
    },
    baseUri: function () { return BASE_URI; }
};

function PreLoad() {

    mm.products.init();
    mm.products.read();

    ko.applyBindings(mm);
}
```

you can also explicitly indicate in what context function should be called:

```
<form id="createProducts" data-bind="submit: function () { products.create($root.products); }">

products: {
    create: function(self) {
        ...
    }
```

in that case $root should point to your view model, so you will pass instance of products object to create function.

Comment: Hi @Slawek! I appreciate your first suggestion to keep the html's data bind as simple as possible. But unfortunately the error persists. :(
The second one solves the problem, but adds complexity to the data bind. Tonight I'll return to this project. Thanks!